# Wordpress crop images not the thumbnail and without plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a function (with PHP) to crop my pictures in wordpress without a plugin. I need it for a gallery-slider and not for the thumbnail.

Can anybody show me an example (in codepen for example or somwhere) how I can make this?

This is my PHP-Code in my index.php or home.php where i want to print it out:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'post_type' => 'home',
    'order'=> 'ASC'      
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args); ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php if(get_field('img1') != '') { ?>
   <div class="gallerySlider">
      <?php the_field('img1'); ?>
   </div>   
<?php } ?>


<?php if(get_field('img2') != '') { ?>
   <div class="gallerySlider">
      <?php the_field('img2'); ?>
   </div>   
<?php } ?>


<?php if(get_field('img3') != '') { ?>
   <div class="gallerySlider">
      <?php the_field('img3'); ?>
   </div>   
<?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

This is in my function.php:

```
if (function_exists('add_image_size')) { 
   add_image_size('biggest',800,800,false);
   add_image_size('big',600,300,array('center','center'));
   add_image_size('small',200,200,array('center','center'));
   add_image_size('smallest',100,100,array('center','center'));
}
```

As you can see, I use ACF for the images. For every post i have more than 3 images. 
Now: How do I call in my index/home.php this function for these images?

Comment: without writing your code for you, I can give you a starting point, http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropimage.php

Comment: so, now i included my code

Comment: Cropping images like the native functionality provided by WordPress? - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, this is possible with WordPress.
Here's an example how to do that.

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 220, array( 'left', 'top' ) ); // Hard crop left top
```

Here the array represent the crop position, the first value in the array is the x axis crop position, the second is the y axis crop position.

x_crop_position ==> ‘left’ ‘center’, or ‘right’.
y_crop_position ==> ‘top’, ‘center’, or ‘bottom’.

And as usual you can print them using

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-size' ); 
}
```

Refer [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) for detailed information.

PS: this will not work with the already uploaded images.

Comment: i don't know how to connect my code from the top with the crop.
i already put the add_image_size in my function.php but in index.php i can't use them or better i don't know how. 

for my gallery-slider i use the ACF images as you can see and there is (for me) the complicated thing

Comment: thanks for your answer and comment! now I included everything

Comment: After adding this code you can use this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to regenerate thumbnails for existing uploaded images. Then you can deactivate this plugin there is no need for future uploads.